# screen share and chatting in php

Tags: php, screen, share, skype4com

I want to make a application in php that will have a chatting module with screensharing option
is there any php source code available to share screen and chatting
Thanks
Shivam

Comment: Sorry, but implementing screen sharing with pure PHP isn't possible.

Comment: Juhana is correct. You cannot do this with PHP since it is server side. You could potentially do this with a java applet that you embed in your webpage. See https://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/ for possible options to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to do screensharing in PHP. Your best/easiest bet for that is most likely an embedded Java applet.

As for the chatting, you could do that very easily in PHP, and make it display messages in "real-time" using AJAX calls to check for new messages.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is impossible, because skype use closed protocols. But you can waste a lot of time for reverse engineering to determine these protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not possible with PHP. However you can combine Javascript and Ajax to get something reasonable out of this. And also Java applets.

Answer (score 0):

For screen sharing, no, PHP is not client-side dynamic- the closest you'll get for a viable solution is by uising JavaScript. As PHP is server-side, content (i.e. the simplest of screen refreshes) would need to be updated/managed server side, in order for the client (user) to see these changes, they would need to reload the script. Given the overheads and impracticalities of doing so, PHP is not viable at all.

Regarding chatting- your best bet is a combination of PHP and Javascript, see [here](http://www.phpfreechat.net/) for one such application